# Long text below two figures

Tags: floats, overleaf, notes, document

In my document I would like to include two figures side by side (this part I know how to do it). Below these two figures, I would like to include a long text, in footnote size, which is the translation of the text inside these two figures. The problem is that because the text is very long, the page does not display it and `footnotesize` is not working. Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, times]{article}
\usepackage{UF_FRED_paper_style}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{My title}
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig1.jpeg}}
\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig2.jpeg}}
\textit{Source:} Origin \\
\textit{Translation:} 
\captionof{\footnotesize{Here I want to add a text with around 20 lines, justified, with the translation of what is inside the figures. 
But footnotesize is not working. 
What appears to me is the text with normal size, and it does not show all the text because there is no space for that in the page}}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Why not putting a short caption AND a footnote, which holds the long text?

Comment: Then how I should do that? Because I tried \caption[My tiyle]{The long text that I want to insert} and it only shows the text, not the figure

Comment: Off-topic: `\footnotesize` is a switch and doesn't take a braces-delimited argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see a need for two `\caption` directives -- or, for that matter, one `\caption` and one `\captionof` statement.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{UF_FRED_paper_style} % I don't have this file...
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman text and math fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\caption{Caption uses \texttt{\string\normalsize}}\label{fig1}

%% there's no need for a '\centering' directive.

\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig1}% % no need for 'jpeg' filename extension
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig2}

\smallskip\footnotesize

\textit{Source}: Origin.

\smallskip
\textit{Legend}: Here I add about twenty lines of text, justified, with 
an explanation of what is shown in the graphs. 
\verb+\footnotesize+ is working fine.
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize. 
More text in footnotesize. More text in footnotesize.
\par

\end{figure}

A cross-reference to figure \ref{fig1}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to put your long text:

- unfortunately my suggestion with using `\footnote{}` doesn't work
- @Mico 's idea is very nice in my view, to put a legend
- `LaTeX` provides many more options for doing so
- here I will show a possibility using `tikz`

Some comments on my modification of your code:

- the `UF_FRED...` package seems to be quite unknown, so I dropped it
- package `graphicx` should be used; option `draft` ignores missing images
- I used a call to `\tikz{ }` to put the text
- inside it just puts one `\node`
- nodes need to provide (empty) text like so `{your long text here};`
- you can modify the appearance of a node using `[ .. ]` to hold formatting statements
- `text width=.8\textwidth`
- `font=\small` (or \huge, or \tiny etc.)
- `align=center`; see [ch. 17.4.3 for more details in the pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.4.3)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[12pt, times]{article}
    %\usepackage{UF_FRED_paper_style}% seems to be hardly known
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}% for images; draft puts dummy boxes
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{My title}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig1.jpeg}}
    \hfill
    {\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig2.jpeg}}
    \textit{Source:} Origin\\
    \textit{Translation:\\
        \tikz{
            \node[text width=.8\textwidth,font=\small,align=center] 
            {Here I want to add a text with 
            around 20 lines, justified, with the translation of what is inside 
            the figures. But footnotesize is not working.  What appears to me 
            is the text with normal size, and it does not show all the text 
            because there is no space for that in the page}% closing \node-text
            }% closing \tikz
        }% closing \textit 
    \label{fig1}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```